# I'm getting error in "this.something" in all activity and mainfest, xml of android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest

I just installed android studio because I reinstalled windows.

While opening my project, at first I got error in every where. Then I

- clean and rebuid the projects
- sync the project with gradle file
- invalidated caches/restart
- deleted .idea and .gradle files
- auto import

**[UPDATE: I again invalidated caches/restart and it worked :)]** But, how can I solve this warning?
I got this warinig while rebuilding the app, might this be reason of showing error?

**error while rebuiding** 
[image: error while rebuiding]

My errors as compared to before are gone but I'm still **getting the errors in xml, manifest, actvities.**

**error in xml** 
[image: error in xml]

**error in mainfest** 
[image: error in mainfest]

**error in activity** 
[image: error in activity]

**error in activity** 
[image: error in activity]

**error is DataAdapter** 
[image: error is DataAdapter]

***I think there might be issue of importing internal files from one to another but don't know to sove this.*** and, I don't know why I'm hiding package name, but I think that is good practice...?

Answer (score 0):

Add [ndkVersion](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#apply-specific-version) to your module's build.gradle

```
android.ndkVersion  "your-installed-ndk-version"
```